# Why did Telegram app suddenly appear on my iPhone? I didn't install it!

Tags: iphone

Telegram was never something I have ever installed manually. So how the heck did it suddenly randomly appear on my phone when I switched it on today. It started up with a notification. I thought heck that's odd. Then I find I had an app I never downloaded. So I immediately trashed the app.

Comment: Did you ever install Telegram on any of your devices?  Do you have Family Sharing?

Comment: @Allan Nope to the above. It's a work iPhone 6s - older generation with most up to date OS it allows.

Comment: @JGFMK You mention it's a work device. Is it signed into a work account?

Comment: Exactly the question I was going to ask that @Ezekiel beat me to.

Comment: No it's not. The only devices I see are ones I am familiar with. The only thing I can surmise is somehow it got installed via another app update. But I am not sure if that is even possible. I have similar apps like WhatsApp, Teams and Skype. Or potentially a service provider adding it via a SIM card. But that sounds  bizarre too.

Comment: EE is my network provider. Another thought - somehow airdropped - I have bluetooth set to 'only my contacts' - but mostly work from home and have used it to send photos to one of my Macbook Pros.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your work phone has an Apple ID same as a private phone, which has Telegram installed on it ?

Comment: No. This is not the case. I do have 2 phones - but Telegram wasn't on the other, a watch and a couple of macbook pros too personal/work - none have the app.

Answer (score 0):

The only way apps get installed are via the App Store or a management profile.

Check for profiles in the settings app.

Unless you’re jailbroken, one of the above avenues placed the app on the phone. From a practical standpoint delete it and then wait and watch would be my advice.

Comment: Do you mean the Apple ID > Show All  for devices? If so that is the info I have provided elsewhere. Nothing else jumps out as if it's been jailbroken - certainly not something I have done. (You can install an app over a cable from a Macbook Pro too btw as I've developed mobile apps in the past by  an ipa file but that's not happened for the app in question)

Comment: No @JGFMK - [profiles are a special item](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration-profiles) shown in the settings app. Check for VPN and device management within that app…

Comment: Right. When I search on VPN setting screen just says Add VPN Configuration. None set.